# Github: not signed in command line

Tags: git, github

My problem appears when I try commit something from my pc I can, but I'm not signed in to my account. But when I commit changes on webside it's.
I added ssh key to my account.

This is my simple git repository: https://github.com/regisik/Fishkers/commits/master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your email from your git config to your account from account settings here: https://github.com/settings/emails

locally you set it alike : `git config --global user.email "your_email@example.com"`

Comment: I just notice that I set wrong email address... Thanks for help